# Free modules over a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, bimodules

Let $M \cong R^n$ be a free $R$-module of rank $n$, where $R$ is an integral domain. Let $S$ be an integral domain such that $(S,+) \cong \Bbb Z^n$ as abelian groups.

Assume that we have a ring morphism $S \to (End(M), +, \circ)$ commuting with the action of $R$ (that is, $r \cdot (s \cdot m) = s \cdot (r \cdot m)$), i.e. $M$ is then a $(R,S)$-bimodule.

Is it true that $M$ is free of rank $1$ over $R \otimes_{\Bbb Z} S$ ?
I'm not sure about the freeness, actually. If this is not true, what conditions ensure that this is valid (e.g. $R$ is a DVR, $S$ is Dedekind, $n \leq 2$, etc.)?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you would need a condition on the map from S, not on R

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your presentation here, we have that $R, S$ are integral domains, such that $S \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. We also have an $(R, S)$-bimodule $M$ such that $M \cong R^n$ as an $R$-module. You are asking under what conditions is $M$ free of rank $1$ over $R \otimes S$?

Comment: @Joppy : I think this is indeed what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is usually not true.  For instance, suppose that $S$ is actually a subring of $R$, and the action of $S$ on $M$ is just given by restricting the action of $R$.  Then $M$ will not be free over $R\otimes_\mathbb{Z} S$ (unless $S$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$), since for each $s\in S$, $s\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes s$ act on $M$ in the same way.

I don't know of any reasonable conditions that would make the answer yes.  Certainly it's not enough to just put conditions on $R$ and $S$ themselves, since $R$ and $S$ could be arbitrarily nice in the example above (for instance, $R$ could a number field and $S$ could be its ring of integers).  What you need is for the actions of $R$ and $S$ on $M$ to be "independent" in some strong way.

Comment: Thank you! My question was indeed too general... Maybe you could have a look at this more precise version: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973182/free-modules-over-a-tensor-product-bis :-)